# Looping through results in mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

I am new to mysqli and having a problem looping through results with mysqli.  Unfortunately, I am only getting a single result.  When I put the query into phpMyAdmin, it comes up with three results.  I believe the relevant code is here and that I am just calling it wrong:

```
$connection = new mysqli($host, $databaseUsername, $databasePassword, $database);

if ($connection->connect_errno > 0) {
    die ('Unable to connect to database [' . $connection->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql = "SELECT clientId, studentFirstName, studentLastName
        FROM clients
        WHERE (studentEmail = '$postEmail') OR (parentEmail = '$postEmail');";  

if (!$result = $connection->query($sql)) {
    die ('There was an error running query[' . $connection->error . ']');
}

echo '<select class = "toolbarDropdown" id = "toolbarDropdown-MultipleAccounts">';

    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row["clientId"].'">'.$row["studentFirstName"].' '.$row["studentLastName"].'</option>';
    }

echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Could you add your actual query please?

Comment: We will need to see the query.

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby Okay, I added the SQL query.  Later in the code I echo $sql and then I copied and pasted that into phpMyAdmin.  In phpMyAdmin, this results in three results.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are missing the closing " at option="value <--  in your HTML

Note that

```
$row = $result->fetch_array()
```

can be replaced by

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc()
```

Doing so, the array for each record you fetch would take half of the size.

Comment: This is what I had originally, before I changed it to what is written above.  Both methods have the same result and only return one row

Comment: Yes you are right, the default fetch style is MYSQL_BOTH. So `fetch_array()` will work too. What does the error log say? Can you enable display_errors for short?

Comment: Ahhh! I just read the edit at the top (missing ", that totally did it.  Thank you so much, its been driving me nuts for hours.