# PHP & MySQL OOP - Why am I not getting a result back?

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop, object

I am unsure on why the full name is not being returned/output in the browser. Can anyone help? I have a classes file that includes specific classes just for a more organised file structure. The database class contains all of the current methods to do with the database and the user class contains the methods for the user, I call some of the methods from database in the user class but I'm sure the scope of the methods and attributes are set correctly?

classes.php:

```
include 'database.php';
include 'user.php';
$user = User::getUserId(1);
echo $user->getName();
```

database.php

```
<?php
require_once("../core/config.php");

class Database {
    private $connection;

    function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }

    public function connect() {
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("Database connection failed: " . 
               mysqli_connect_error() . 
               " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
            );
        }
    }

    public function disconnect() {
        if(isset($this->connection)) {
            mysqli_close($this->connection);
            unset($this->connection);
        }
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);
        if (!$result) {
            die("Database query failed.");
        } 
        return $result;
    }

    public function prepare($data) {
        $escString = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $data);
        return $escString;
    }

    public function fetchArray($results) {
        return mysqli_fetch_array($results);
    }
}

$db = new Database();

?>
```

user.php

```
<?php

class User {

    public $userId;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $email;
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $access;
    public $active;

    public static function getUsers() {
        return self::getBySQL("SELECT * FROM users");
    }

    public static function getUserId($id=0) {
        global $db;
        $result = self::getBySQL("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId={$id} LIMIT 1");
        return !empty($result) ? array_shift($result) : false;
    }

    public static function getBySQL($sql) {
        global $db;
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        $objArray = array();
        while ($row = $db->fetchArray($result)) {
            $objArray[] = self::instantiate($row);
        }
        return $objArray;
    }

    public function getName() {
        if (isset($this->firstname) && isset($this->lastname)) {
            return $this->firstname . " " . $this->lastname;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    private static function instantiate($record) {
        $object = new self;

        foreach($record as $attr=>$value){
            if($object->hasAttr($attr)) {
                $object->$attr = $value;
            }
        }
        return $object;
    }

    private function hasAttr($attr) {
        $objectVars = get_object_vars($this);
        return array_key_exists($attr, $objectVars);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: What is result of var_dump($user);

Comment: @RaviHirani object(User)#4 (8) { ["userId"]=> string(1) "1" ["username"]=> NULL ["password"]=> NULL ["email"]=> NULL ["firstname"]=> NULL ["lastname"]=> NULL ["access"]=> NULL ["active"]=> NULL }

Comment: Have you proper checked that user exist in DB? And if yes then all fields are NULL in DB?

Comment: @RaviHirani Yeah the user exists with userId 1, and what do the values have to be null? Each field do have values, my own details as I just entered me in the database for the first record.

Comment: @RaviHirani I just used the query in phpmyadmin and it returns the record with userId 1 but the dump is returning NULL for the other values so is the issue in the actual method ?

Comment: Yes. Problem is in getBySQL function.

Comment: Checkthis link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942268/looping-through-results-in-mysqli

Comment: @RaviHirani Thanks, but I still can't work out what's going wrong, I am now using an associative array but still same issue, dump shows NULL values

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code works. Here is a self contained example:

```
<?php
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "sotest_users");

function query($mysqli, $text) {
    print 'Query: ' . $text . PHP_EOL;
    $result = $mysqli->query($text);
    if ($result === false) {
        print 'Query error: ' . $mysqli->error . PHP_EOL;
        die();
    }
    return $result;
}

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
query($mysqli, 'drop database if exists ' . DB_NAME);
query($mysqli, 'create database ' . DB_NAME);
$mysqli->select_db(DB_NAME);
query($mysqli, 'create table users (userId integer, username text, password text)');
query($mysqli, 'insert into users (userId, username, password) values (1, "test", "test")');

$result = query($mysqli, 'select * from users where userId=1');
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    print json_encode($row) . PHP_EOL;
}
$result->close();


// Your code here

class Database {
    //...
}

$db = new Database();

class User {
    //...
}

print 'Start' . PHP_EOL;
$user = User::getUserId(1);
var_dump($user);
//echo $user->getName();
```

Output:

```
Query: drop database if exists sotest_users
Query: create database sotest_users
Query: create table users (userId integer, username text, password text)
Query: insert into users (userId, username, password) values (1, "test", "test")
Query: select * from users where userId=1
{"userId":"1","username":"test","password":"test"}
Start
class User#6 (8) {
  public $userId =>
  string(1) "1"
  public $username =>
  string(4) "test"
  public $password =>
  string(4) "test"
  public $email =>
  NULL
  public $firstname =>
  NULL
  public $lastname =>
  NULL
  public $access =>
  NULL
  public $active =>
  NULL
}
```

Full code is [here](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/blob/master/quick-test/php-test-db.php).
Fields after the `password` are empty only because I didn't add them to the `users` table.

But I must say, that what are you doing in general is wrong, both in terms of OOP (global variables, static methods, public properties, etc) and in terms of db handling (lack of error handling, direct variable injection into sql).

If this is a real project - better switch to some framework, like [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/).

If you are learning - find and read something about proper OOP usage and best db practices in php. [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) is a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you! I will most definitely look into doing everything correctly, also will look into yii!